# MySQL SELECT COUNT(*) takes minutes on an empty table

Tags: mysql

Not much more to say.

```
mysql> select count(*) from mytable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 2.35 sec)
```

There seems to be nothing extraordinary with the table. Only a few varchars and a few decimals. No keys, no indexes. It's the only table on the database.

How can I investigate this?

Comment: how do you execute  the  query (console, ìde ..??)

Comment: @scaisEdge, see the picture. It is from the console.

Comment: Is MySQL locally installed? What f you re-execute the same query, still over a minute?

Comment: @FDavidov Yes and Yes.

Comment: OS is Linux or Windows?

Comment: Just for test  .. try close and reenter in console ..

Comment: I would also suggest to monitor computer resources while SELECT executes.

Comment: @FDavidov Linux, ubuntu

Comment: @scaisEdge I've already done that, already rebooted the OS too.

Comment: Try monitoring OS resources.

Comment: What else is running on this server? What size server is it? Is it swapping?

Comment: Is your "computer" actually a VM?

Comment: @BillKarwin No idea if it's swapping, how do I check this? This server is my laptop. Chrome is running :D

Comment: @FDavidov No, it's actually my laptop's OS that mysql is installed on.

Comment: Did you monitor the system while executing (second console)? The first thing you need to confirm is that the bottleneck is NOT in the OS. Please re-execute while monitoring the OS.

Comment: `vmstat 5 5` and watch the `si` and `so` columns. If they're anything other than zero, you're swapping. A common reason for this when using MySQL is that you've allocated too much InnoDB buffer pool. I once helped a company troubleshoot their MySQL test server, it was very slow. They had allocated over 8GB to the buffer pool. I asked how much physical RAM on this machine? It was only 1GB.

Comment: @FDavidov hey, I re-run it again and it's not happening anymore. Earlier I said Yes, because it happened again at that time. I had just deleted some 5M rows from the table and everything was lagging, so now I suspect that it's what Bill Karwin is suggesting, and it was swapping or something.

Comment: @BillKarwin See above. I will keep what you just said in mind for the future, thank you.

Comment: Well, having a table with no keys and no indices with few million records explains it all.

Comment: @FDavidov No, I said I had just deleted it. So when I ran those queries the table was empty. But just before that it had a few million records.

Comment: When you delete a lot of rows in InnoDB, there's a lot of work internally that it does to "clean up" and that can last for a while. It's probably making your laptop work really hard during this time. Maybe it'll get faster after it's done with that. In the future, if you want to empty all rows from a table more efficiently, use `TRUNCATE TABLE` (but that can only truncate down to zero rows, leaving the table completely empty).

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you very much for your vast wisdom kind sir :-)

Comment: OK, now it is clear (I was confused by your statement and the fact that the COUNT yielded `0`). When you run a query (any query), you may see strange behavior in a number of cases; for instance, immediately after you started your DBMS (some initializations that take place in parallel to your ability to _talk_ to the DBMS), and in cases like yours, when the system is doing some background activities (e.g. garbage disposal and re-organization). To really test performance, you need to wait till system is IDLING (meaning, no or minor work is taking place in the background).